# What's the Right Amount of Conditioner to Use for Thick, Male Hair?

Tags: hair, hygiene, topical-cream-gel, measurement, hair-conditioner

I tend to use almost a handful, but I don't know if that's dumb. I don't have long hair, either. On the top, I cut to 8 or 7, usually, and that's the longest I have it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about health.

Comment: @Marko, this isn't the type of question that will be answered properly here. I'd suggest you ask your barber or hairstylist.